# Android webview not supporting html5 css3 animations

Tags: android, html, css

I have a game developed using html5 css3. I have used webview to wrap the game as an android app. But the animations is failing when I run it. I tried to search the problem and found that **Android only support animations with a single changing property. When multiple animations occur simultaneously then it fails**. So this was the reason my game animations are not working and some images disappeared. I also tried using chromeview (user-defined java class) from github instead of webview but it didn't help too. Please help me out to run my game smoothly on android.

Answer (score 0):

From KitKat (Android 4.4) it supports modern HTML5 and CSS features.. More details [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview)